# Posting a message to Groupme API with Django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views, python-requests

I am trying to post a message using [Groupme's API](https://dev.groupme.com/docs/v3#messages_create)  from within a Django view. To help with HTTP posting I am using the [requests python package.](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) I also use the json python module to format json data.

```
import requests, json

data = json.dumps({"message":{"source_guid":"random_string", "text": "message_to_send"}})
send = requests.post("https://api.groupme.com/v3/groups/:group_id/message?token=my_access_token", data=data)

send.json()
```

Of course :groupe_id and my_access_token are actual numbers in my code. But, this always returns:

```
{u'meta': {u'code': 400, u'errors': [u'text is required']}}
```

Instead of a status 201.
Can anyone please tell me why it is not recognizing the "text" entry in the json data? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be posting to:

```
https://api.groupme.com/v3/groups/:group_id/messages
```

with a payload like:

```
{
   "message": {
     "source_guid": "c8bf78dd-c17c-4d1d-9029-1689764436a1",
     "text": "So text....."
   }
}
```

put your access token in the http header `X-Access-Token`
and ensure that your `Content-Type` header is `application/json`

Answer (score 0):

Just use 'json' in the input parameters for the POST request rather than 'data'.

```
data = {"message":{"source_guid":"random_string","text":"message_to_send"}}
send = requests.post("https://api.groupme.com/v3/groups/:group_id/message?token=my_access_token", json=data)
print send.text
```